# Prove $|b| \le 1$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

We know this equation doesn't have any solution.

> $a\cos x + b\cos 3x \gt 1$

Now prove that $|b| \le 1$

My attempt : I rewrote it and I've got $a\cos x + b(-3\cos x + 4\cos^3x) -1\gt 0
$ .
Now I'm stuck here and unable to find interval of $b$ .

Comment: There must be something wrong here ... Suppose $a=0$ and $b=10$. The inequation $10\cos(3x)>1$ certainly *does* have solutions !

Comment: @Adren I wrote the exact question which was in the book .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read you question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is :

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\,a\cos\left(x\right)+b\cos\left(3x\right)\leq1$$

Replacing $x$ with $\pi-x$ we get :

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\,\left|a\cos\left(x\right)+b\cos\left(3x\right)\right|\leq1$$

For $x=0$ and $x={\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{3}}$ respectively :

$$\left|a+b\right|\leq1\textrm{ and }\left|\frac{a}{2}-b\right|\leq1$$

Hence :

$$\max\left\{ -1-a,\,-1+\frac{a}{2}\right\} \leq b\leq\min\left\{ 1-a,\,1+\frac{a}{2}\right\}$$

Considering successively the cases $a\geq0$ and $a\leq0$, we see that $\left|b\right|\leq1$.

Comment: When we replace $x$ with $\pi-x$ we get : $-a\cos\left(x\right)-b\cos\left(3x\right)\leq1$ Not $\left|a\cos\left(x\right)+b\cos\left(3x\right)\right|\leq1$

Comment: Of course, but since we have already $a\cos\left(x\right)+b\cos\left(3x\right)\leq1$, it does the job ! Remind that $|X|\le Y$ is equivalent to ($X\le Y$ and $-X\le Y$).